# ReloadData after UITableView updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add rows to my tableView like this:

```
[myArray addObject:@"Apple"];

[myTableView beginUpdates];
[myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```

The problem is that the cells don't get refreshed. The textLabels do no correspond to the datasource array.

I fix the problem by adding:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

but that makes the nice insertion animation go away.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: as @stephen-darlington said , when you **addObject:** .It adds to the end index of mutable array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addObject:` adds an object to the *end* of a mutable array. Then, on your next line, you tell the table view that there's a new row to display at the very *top* of the table. Unless you have your array "backwards," it looks as though you're telling the table to "insert" a cell in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the item to the end of the array, but adding a row to the beginning of the table... Try it like this:

```
NSString* obj = @"Apple";
[myArray addObject:obj];

[myTableView beginUpdates];
[myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[myArray indexOfObject:obj] inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```